# How to extract even cells from a column in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I don't know how to exctract every second row to second column to have in result in this file https://mega.nz/#!18sAFAwC!YvRRS9zGQOvnVCwOS9KZXQtI7h7Bdle9RhTVdnFdqUE something like :

- **column1**   ; **column2**
- ab und zu ; od czasu do czasu
- abbiegen  ; skręcić

I'm playing with this for long time so I ask question. Thank for all responses

Answer (score 1):

In B1, put the formula `=IF(ISEVEN(ROW(A1)),A1,"")`

This returns A1 if it's on an even row, else returns nothing. Copy the formula down. You should get values in even rows only.

Filter the B column to exclude empty cells, then just copy & paste the values shown.

If you have Excel 2010 or later, you could also do array formula.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

`=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A1,"")`

Multiply it from B1 to last nonempty cell and in column "B" will appear values only on odd rows.

Comment: If you want values to appear on every third or fourth row change number  2 in the formula to 3 or 4 and so on.

Comment: I cannot cope with this because excel says that it's error of formula. I downloaded excel 2007 and it said the same, error of formula. Can you do this by yourself and upload result? :)

Comment: Try to change =IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0;A1;"")

Comment: "We found a problem with this formula"